# Python Exception Processing

Tags: python, exception, repeat

```
N=int(input("Find Prime Number:"))
ans = [2]
count=0
for i in range(3,N+1):
    for j in ans:
        if i % j ==0:
            break
    else:
        ans.append(i)
print(ans)
```

This is a code for finding the prime number.

I wonder how "else" works when there is no "if" in the repetition.

Answer (score 1):

The Python language supports the use of the `else` keyword as part of the syntax of a `for` statement.  Most folks steer clear of it because it is an oddity, but it will execute if and only if the `for` loop is exited "naturally" - that is without executing `break.`  For that reason it is sometimes referred to as the "no-break" conditional. In the sample code given in the question, `i` is appended to `ans` only if the break statement in the `for` loop above it is never reached.

Comment: Here is a [good article on the topic](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/break_else.html).

Answer (score 1):

The else block just after for/while is executed only when the loop is NOT terminated by a break statement.

```
    for i in range(3,N+1):
      for j in ans:
        if i % j ==0:
            break
    else:
        ans.append(i)
```

It will start in else part only after loop has completed.

reference :

- https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_for_else.asp
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/using-else-conditional-statement-with-for-loop-in-python/